# HTML5 Video, Only Fire on FIrst onplay function

Tags: video, html5-video

The below script works great but it fires every time the play button is pressed (play, pause, play, etc).  I'm looking to modify this onplay video event to only fire on the first Play event.  I'm familiar with the other functions ondurationchange, etc. but they do not work for my setup as I need to preload the video and don't want the function to fire until the play button is actually pressed.  Any help would be super appreciated!

```
var vid = document.getElementById("videoContent");
                    vid.onplay = function loadXMLDoc() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach yourself to the "canplaythrough" event with:
`vid.addEventListener("canplaythrough", loadXmlDoc);`

This event is fired once, as soon as the video has been completely loaded.

For more information on this event, check out [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the onplay event in the event function

```
var vid = document.querySelector("video");
vid.onplay = myFunction;

function myFunction(){
  vid.onplay = null;
  // do somthing....
}
```

Or you can use a global variable as a condition which you change to true the first time it fires

```
var ran = false;
function myFunction() {
  if (!ran) {
    ran = true;
    // do something...
  }
}
```